# Not able to share dependencies on a controller

Tags: ember.js

I have an application running with Ember 1.12.0. I have a simple template called `/app/templates/repositories.hbs` with this content :

```
{{controllers.user.login}}
```

I added this in the controller `app/controllers/repositories.js` :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: "user",
});
```

I have this route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var user = this.modelFor('user');
    console.log(user);
    return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/'+user.login+'/repos');
  }
});
```

And this router :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'} );
  this.resource('user', {path: '/users/:login'}, function() {
    this.resource('repositories');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

According to [the documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/). I should show the user login but I have just nothing. It show the user object in the console but not in the view.

Is the a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `user` model fetched in `user` route (as you can see it in console, the `modelFor` works properly). However, you are trying to get `login` object on `user` controller - I think that it's not defined. What you really want to get is `login` property of the object that is the model for `user` route (probably it's the user, but you didn't posted your `user` route code).

To use these two models in one controller you don't need to share these controllers. All you need is the model for `user` route. Thus, you can leave your `model` hook as follows:

```
model: function(params) {
  return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/'+user.login+'/repos');
}
```

And write your `setupController` method as follows:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set("model", model);
  controller.set("user", this.modelFor("user");
}
```

And in your template you would have your `repos` from AJAX and the `user` property with that property.

```
{{user.login}}
```

On the other hand, you could, with some fixes, use the shared `user` controller obtaining same effect, but it's not what you need - you need only the model for that controller, not the whole object.

Comment: It works but it strange because the doc does not contains that.

Comment: What you mean that docs does not contain that? If you would like to use shared dependencies, you would have to use in template something like `controllers.user.user.login`, as the `user` object is defined **on** `user` controller. However, as I said, what you need is a model, not a controller. Therefore, the solution I proposed is cleaner.